# Zero byte disappear when get hid feature report using ioctl() in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, hid, ioctl

I would like to get a hid feature report from a device. Since the host system is Ubuntu18.04, I followed this [example](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/hidraw/hid-example.c) (from line 125 to line 135). However, the loaded data is not complete. For example, the feature report is **uint32_t 0xFFEEDDCC** but what I get is **DD EE FF**, the zero byte **CC** disappears. So, I was wondering why the zero byte disappears and how to get complete data.

Below are my codes.

```
uchar buf[reportSize];  // reportSize = 5, in case the report id occupies 1 byte

int fdevice = open(devicePath, O_RDWR);

// get feature report
buf[0] = reportID;  
featureResults = ioctl(fdevice, HIDIOCGFEATURE(reportSize), buf);  // featureResults = 3 but should be 4

if (featureResults < 0)
{
    perror("HIDIOCGFEATURE");
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < featureResults; i++)
         printf("%hhx ", buf[i]);    // only show DD EE FF
    puts("\n");
}
```

I tried with larger reportSize e.g. 256 as well but it still does not work. Besides, buf[-1], buf[featureResults] and buf[featureResults+1] are *not* the lost data.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is `synTimeStamp`? Is that supposed to be `buf`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you very much for your notice. I have modified the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description in this [web](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hid/hidraw.txt), it seems that HIDIOCGFEATURE(len) would always skip the zeroth byte and start from the first byte. So, I add a placeholder byte (LSB) to the hid feature report (firmware). In this way, the placeholder would be skipped and the data could be read correctly.

Any other solution would be very much appreciated.